# What is happening during a CloudFront deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I'm using a web application setup in AWS where my backend is hosted on Elastic Beanstalk, and my frontend is stored in an S3 bucket. Both are served through CloudFront as a CDN. I've been following a specific deployment process, but I have questions regarding the timing of CloudFront changes and cache invalidation.

Here's my deployment procedure:

- Duplicate my Elastic Beanstalk backend.
- Deploy the duplicated backend with changes.
- Push frontend changes to a staging folder in my S3 bucket.
- Change the origins of my CloudFront distribution to point to the updated S3 content and duplicated backend.
- Wait for the CloudFront deployment to complete.
- Invalidate the CloudFront cache.

My concern lies in the period between the change of CloudFront origins and the cache invalidation. Specifically, I'm unsure about the following:

1. What exactly happens during the CloudFront deployment? Could this impact the accessibility of my updated frontend content?
2. Is it necessary to wait for the CloudFront deployment to finish before initiating the cache invalidation process? Or can I proceed with cache invalidation as soon as I've updated the CloudFront origins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a risk of inconsistency until you invalidate the cache.
I mean one client might fetch a version n of a resource from the cache and a version n+1 of another resource from the new origin, and version n+1 of your backend API. This could lead to unexpected behaviour or rendering.

I invite you to look at [CloudFront continuous deployment feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/continuous-deployment.html).
Basically you have 2 distributions one primary and a staging one.
The staging one can be associated to your second S3 origin and second backend API.
You can invalidate the cache of the staging distribution then proceed with the rollout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I already took a look at this, and what buggs me is the fact that "When you promote a staging distribution, CloudFront copies the configuration from the staging distribution to the primary distribution. CloudFront also disables the continuous deployment policy and routes all traffic to the primary distribution". To me it looks like promoting stagging distribution is doing exactly the same thing I'm already doing.

Comment: Not quite. When you change the origin of your unique distribution and until you invalidate the cache in each POP you have an inconsistant state. 
The approach with 2 distributions is consistent (B/G or canary).  
You can manage it your way with 2 distributions, updating your DNS entries to switch traffic from one to the other, CF continuous deployment is automating these operations.

Comment: Yes updating the DNS entries would make it consistent. However for multiple reason we would like to avoid changing our DNS configuration at each deployment. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that the other answer that discusses managing multiple distributions and using DNS to switch traffic between them isn't that straight forward. I know OP isn't using the DNS switching solution, but for posterity, it seems worth mentioning here.

CloudFront doesn't actually care what distribution your DNS points to. Once it receives the traffic, it routes it to the correct distribution based on the host header that matches the alternate domain on the distribution. This means that your DNS can point to literally any CloudFront IP, and it will still go to the correct distribution. So DNS switching alone won't gain you anything here, you'd actually need to migrate the alternate domain names between the distributions, which is possible to automate, but more involved.

More info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-restrictions, specifically:

> CloudFront sends the request to the distribution with the more specific name match, regardless of the distribution that the DNS record points to.

This quote is specifically referring to when you have overlapping alternate domain names when using wildcards, but it's true for all scenarios, not just that one. This was a hard lesson learned as this isn't well documented or the obvious behavior of CloudFront.